# Does SQL Server update persisted computed columns when a function is altered?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dependencies, persistence, sql-server-2017

If you have a persisted computed column that uses a function to calculate its value, and you then alter the function, will SQL Server automatically update all of the persisted values in the computed column using the new version of the function?

Comment: You shouldn't be able to alter the function if it is referenced by a computed column.

Comment: I tried to set up a test case so I could explore this issue, but it appears @ZLK is right.  I couldn't alter the function when it is used by a computed column.  Can you show us your code?

Comment: @DavidDubois I don't have any relevant test code yet, but this may pose an issue for us in the future. It sounds like we need to make sure the function is in its final form, before we build tables with computed columns. Dropping and re-creating the computed column would be a huge hassle, since there will be many dependencies on that computed column, and the function is too slow to execute every time we need it (hence the persisted computed column). Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Giffyguy . . . Not exactly.  You can drop the column, drop the function, recreate the function, and recreate the column.